# Question about AccountController and _LoginPartial in sample project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-b2c

I am currently familiarizing myself with both the MVC framework and Azure B2C logins / credentials. The goal is to implement some of the logic provided in the sample project to an existing project. Before getting into details about my troubles with my own project, I was not able to figure out the following:

The sample app provided (cf. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi) contains a class AuthController.cs, which provides logic for Signing In / Out, etc. The methods in the AuthController appear to be called when using a partial view _LoginPartial, e.g.

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sign up / Sign in", "SignUpSignIn", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "signUpSignInLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

The sign-in-method in the AccountController takes an argument `string redirectUrl`, e.g

```
public void SignUpSignIn(string redirectUrl)
        {
            redirectUrl = redirectUrl ?? "/";

            // Use the default policy to process the sign up / sign in flow
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl });
            return;
        }
```

Now, the controller does not seem to be accessible when Debugging, thus I cannot figure out from where the parameter `redirectUrl` is passed. The reason behind this is that I would like to implement the `SignUpSignIn` method in an already existing controller class.
What is the relationship between the partial class and the controller and from where do I get this `redirectUrl`. I am sorry if my question seems trivial, but I am currently making a transition from classic ASP.NET to MVC.

Comment: The redirectUrl is the URL that will be redirected after come back from Azure

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So am I right in the assumption that the the redirectUrl in question corresponds to the Reply URL I set in Azure. I guess that is why the redirectUrl is specified in the web.config and the Global.cs class. So does the controller, in this case, draw the information from the web.config and Global.cs or does it automatically process an incoming url?.

Comment: Is the  the redirectUrl that you will set when you do the call to Azure

Comment: Thanks a mil for clarifying this matter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the main domain name where you're hosting your app as a reply URL in the AAD registration for your app and pass it as the redirect_uri when redirecting to AAD to allow the user to sign in.

AAD will only redirect the access token to URLs that are specified as Reply URLs in the app registration in AAD.

So in this case, redirectUrl has been set to "https://localhost:44316/". The controller gets the redirectUrl value from the web.config file.

It must match with the Reply URL configured in Azure AD.

Comment: I did not quite get the gist of the first paragraph in your reply. This is what my section <appSettings> well except some of the names <add key="ida:Tenant" value="my_tenant.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <add key="ida:TenantId" value="abc-123" />
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="xyz-456" />
    <add key="ida:ClientSecret" value="secret" />
    <add key="ida:AadInstance" value="https://my_tenant.b2clogin.com/{0}/{1}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
    <add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44347" />
    <add key="ida:Sign up and sign in" value="my_sign_up" />
...

Comment: I still do not know if the error/s is/are in my web.config or Azure setup, since, in _theSignUpSignIn_ method, the value of _redirect_ appears to be null and in the end is set to "/", which causes the application return a 404 and some other errors.

Comment: Almost forgot another thing that has been bothering me while checking out the sample project for possible use in an existing application. It seems that I cannot access the _SignUpSignIn_ method when using the Debugger. I would like to take a look at what is inside _redirectUrl_ at this particular moment. Why is it that the Debugger is not triggered? When creating a new class _AccountController.cs_ in a new project and linking that to a SignIn-page, I can however access the method using the debugger, revealing that _redirectUrl_ is empty.